# Declaring a string at run time with variables

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I am trying to create a string with parameters that I pass to a web service, but I never know how many parameters there are going to be until runtime.

All of the parameters are stored in an array, and I iterate through the array, adding each one the the string.

The variables on the .php side are labeled field1, field2, field3, etc.

My problem lies when I try to declare the string in the for loop.  I am trying to use `x` and append that to the word "field" so that I can end up with field1, field2, filed3, etc.

When I try to do this, there is an error message saying that there were more parameters than expected.

Here's what I have:

```
NSString *URLWithParameters = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.mywebsite/service?"];

for (int x = 0; x < [fields count]; x++) {

    NSString *temp = [NSString stringWithString:@"field%i=%@&", x, (NSString *)[fields objectAtIndex:x]];

    URLWithParameters = [URLWithParameters stringByAppendingString:temp];

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stringWithString` should be `stringWithFormat`.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
NSString *temp = [NSString stringWithString:@"field%i=%@&", x, (NSString *)[fields objectAtIndex:x]];
```

to:

```
NSString *temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"field%i=%@&", x, (NSString *)[fields objectAtIndex:x]];
```

---

**Note:**

Why You use `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.mywebsite/service?"]` when You can use it directly like this:

```
NSString *URLWithParameters = @"http://www.mywebsite/service?";
```

or using `stringWithformat`:

```
NSString *URLWithParameters = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"http://www.mywebsite/service?"];
```